# To use bokeh Slider with arrays

Tags: slider, bokeh

First line is ok, but...why nothing happens when I change slide value? Some help please! (rotateimg is an 480x360 array). It seems like update_line function doesn't work...

```
output_notebook()


TOOLS="pan, box_zoom, reset, save, crosshair"

slider = Slider(start=1, end=360, value=250, step=1)

# Original dataset
x = np.arange(0,len(rotateimg),1)
y = [img[slider.value][i] for i in  xrange(len(x))]

print(len(x))
print(len(y))



# create a new plot with a title and axis labels
p = figure(title="Brillo en una línea de la imagen", x_axis_label='x', y_axis_label='Brillo',tools=TOOLS)
figline = p.line(x, y, line_width=2)

def update_line(attr, old, new):
    x = np.arange(0,len(rotateimg),1)
    new_y = [img[slider.value][i] for i in  xrange(len(x))]

    figline.data_source.data['y'] = new_y


slider.on_change('value', update_line)
layout = row(
    widgetbox(slider),
    p
)

#output_file("slider.html", title="slider.py example")

show(layout)
#
```

Comment: `on_change` callbacks only work in conjunction with a bokeh server. There are a variety of ways to use and embed a Bokeh server, including in notebooks. But SO is not a great place to have this discussion since it is not a "clear cut answer".  Please feel free to come by the project mailing list however https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/#!forum/bokeh

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'm working on Jupyter-notebook. ok, I will use the project mailing list.